# how to generate the javasource from WSDL?

Tags: java, wsdl

I have tried Axis2Code generator and Xfire for generating javasource code from WSDL, but it is not able to connect(stating Connection Refused), so is the case with SOAPUI.

But I am able to browse the same WSDL in my browser.

Is there anyother API which can help generate code from WSDL ?

kindly suggest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

U have to install jwsdp(java web service development pack).
Then u can generate java source in many ways.either by `ant target <wsdl2java>` or directly by cammand line as `xjc -wsdl <wsdlurl> -d <directory>`.

Comment: where am i supposed to add thsi line ?

Comment: I told u have to install jwsdp.then u can run command xjc from command line.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest one is to use `wsimport` command provided by your JDK bin directory

```
wsimport -keep -verbose http://localhost:9000/helloWorld/v1?wsdl -p xjc.generated.hello -d outdir
```